# Capturing and printing the extraction progress of 7-Zip in a PowerShell console

Tags: powershell, console, 7zip

I have a PowerShell script which, amoungst other things, extracts files using 7-Zip.

```
"Starting decompression of [$filePath]..."
& $7ZipPath "x" $filePath "-o$extractionPath" "-aos" | Out-Host
```

I've been switching `Out-Host` to `Out-Null` as it looks a bit messy for what I'm trying to acheive at the moment - I know if I add `-bsp1` I can get extraction progress - but it introduces 7z each time and puts every updated percentage on a seperate line and looks kind of messy.

My question is: Is there any way to capture the progress percentage of `-bps1` and have it print in the console in a more compact manner - either a progress bar or just a single line of text with the updating percentage?

Comment: `Out-Host` -> `Write-Host -NoNewline`?

Comment: If it's a normal zip file, an alternative would be [Expand-Archive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive) which will show a progress bar.

Comment: Provided the OP is running PowerShell v5 or newer, that is.

Comment: I guess Expand-Archive doesn't work on `.7z` files?

Comment: No. .7z is 7-zip's own proprietary format.

Answer (score 2):

I managed what I wanted like this:

```
"Extracting [$filePath]..."
& $7ZipPath "x" $filePath "-o$extractionPath" "-aos" "-bsp1" | out-string -stream | Select-String -Pattern "\d{1,3}%" -AllMatches | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value } | foreach {
    [System.Console]::SetCursorPosition(0, [System.Console]::CursorTop) 
    Write-Host "Progress:" $_ -NoNewLine
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works, but if there are already files and folders from that archive (unpacked earlier), the counter will never reach 100% so you have to address this as well.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix for the 'never reaches 100%' issue in UnluckyForSome9's answer:

```
& $7ZipPath "x" $filePath "-o$extractionPath" "-aos" "-bsp1" | out-string -stream | Select-String -Pattern "\d{1,3}%" -AllMatches | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches.Value } | foreach {
[System.Console]::SetCursorPosition(0, [System.Console]::CursorTop) 
Write-Host "Progress:" $_ -NoNewLine
}
[System.Console]::SetCursorPosition(0, [System.Console]::CursorTop) 
Write-Host "Progress:" 100%
```